# Unity3D IPointerDownHandler on other object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code like that

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class Area : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public Image Area;
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data){ //some code...}
}
```

If I add the class on the Image it works fine, but I'd like to add class to a gameMaganer object and set the image to public value Area and get OnPointerDown on it.
Possible?

Comment: What do you mean by adding a class on an image?

Comment: Cid, I mean that I drag class (script) on the image in Unity inspector

Comment: Well, in that case, yes you can add any scripts to gameobjects

Comment: it would be vary different from what i need)

Comment: Your question is too broad, yes you can set an image as public, yes you can implement OnPointerDown in scripts (hopefuly)

Comment: but how to do that?

Comment: drag and drop your script on the gameobject ? I don't understand your question

Comment: I want to add Script to an Object on scene, but get touches from image. i will have ling on the image in script and want to add to the imate the listenner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do is not possible with only one script. You need at least two scripts:

1. One on the image, implementing the `IPointerDownHandler` interface and raising an event so that your 2nd script can listen to it
2. One one your other gameobject, listening to the event raised by the 1st script:

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

[System.Serializable]
public class PointerEvent : UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent<PointerEventData> {} ;

public class PointerDownHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public PointerEvent OnPointerDownEvent ;
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if( OnPointerDownEvent != null )
            OnPointerDownEvent.Invoke( data ) ;
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class Area : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PointerDownHandler PointerDownHandler;

    private void Start()
    {
        OnPointerDownEvent.AddListener( OnPointerDown ) ;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data){ //some code...}
}
```